# How to go to site that is uploaded on github?

Tags: github, repository, vs-web-site-project

This may be a silly question. But, I can't determine how to go to any site of which I can see repository on github. Like, https://github.com/jwasham/computer-science-flash-cards I saw in my github recommendations so how can I access this site?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is hosted by [GitHub pages](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages), that would be a "project pages", that is available at `http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>`.
In this case: http://jwasham.github.io/computer-science-flash-cards, which returns 404 (not found)

That means the site is hosted elsewhere, and the [`README.md`](https://github.com/jwasham/computer-science-flash-cards/blob/53d6e3627adbc30f16cff88e7e686b345f4eb7f6/README.md) mentions: https://startupnextdoor.com/flash-cards-site-complete/